# Angularjs html5Mode page refresh breaks the routing in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs-routing

I am performing angularjs routing in my asp.net application.I have a folder name template which consist of 3 html pages Home,About,Error.
Here is my app.js file

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate']);

app.controller('HomeController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.Message = "We are in home page";
});
app.controller('AboutController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.Message = "We are in about page";
});
app.controller('ErrorController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.Message = "404 page not found";
});

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
         when('/', {
             redirectTo: function () {
                 return '/home';
             }
         }).
        when('/home', {
            templateUrl: '/template/Home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        }).
        when('/about', {
            templateUrl: '/template/About.html',
            controller: 'AboutController'
        }).
         when('/error', {
             templateUrl: '/template/Error.html',
             controller: 'ErrorController'
         }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/error'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Home.html consist of

```
<div ng-controller="HomeController">
<h1>Home Page</h1>
<h3>{{Message}}</h3>
```

and so on.

In my Layout.cshtml file I have included the module myApp and base attribute.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <base href="/" />
```

Body has define some links

```
<body>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/erro">Invalid Url</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div data-ng-view="" id="ng-view" class="slide-animation"></div>
</div>
```

Routing working fine when I navigate from home to others . But when I refreshes about page it gives resource not found error.For this I have also included server side rewrite like this in my web.config file.

```
   <rewrite>
        <rules> 
          <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />                                 
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
```

[image]

Still the problem remains need helping in solving it . Thanks.

Comment: The page at glance looks fine. Is your redirect rule working fine? 
PS: Ideally you should return landing page response for all urls than rewriting. In simple words if you redirect from /about to /home, then when you referesh about page you will end up with home page.

Comment: No when I refresh about page error come resource not found see my updated question

Comment: Your home url is /home its / so redirect to that. Your webserver does not know what it has to do with /home. Its defined in your angular app.

Comment: PS: I am not an expert in ASP and IIS so can't comment on that but it looks like it has nothing to do with angular it is your redirect logic which i feel is having a problem

Comment: I have edited that in my code now url is ="/" still same problem

Comment: Can you try rewrite with an empty project? Something with only index.html

Comment: Why I have to solve this in this project only there is little missing in the code which I dont getting it

Comment: another suggestion i can give you is try with explicit url and no condition

Comment: <rule name="About Rule" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^about/" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
          </rule>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have solved it by making changes in Route.Config file

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

by replacing this with

```
 routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Application",
       url: "{*url}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

Comment: It works for me. But what I should do with logout form? javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit() It's ignored.

Comment: I find that when I hit refresh, the proper view appears again...but the route is dropped from the URL - so a 2nd refresh loads my main page again.  For instance I'm at localhost/home (hit F5) home is reloaded, but the url in the browser changes to localhost/ (hit F5) main page reloaded.  Any ideas?

Comment: anyone using Asp.Net Core: the `url` param is now called `template`

Answer (score 0):

You have to redirect to your base URL (where your Angular App can start), not `url="/home"`, but `url="/"`

Comment: Problem remains still