# AngularJS+MVC - Error 404 refreshing page

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a web application using AngularJS (v1.4.9)+ASP.NET MVC.

I've enabled the html5mode for pretty links, but I've this problem: when I browse to my first page of the application (Login) and I try to refresh that page, for example with F5 button, I receive a 404 error.

I've searched on StackOverflow and found this discussion: [Angularjs html5Mode page refresh breaks the routing in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30322892/angularjs-html5mode-page-refresh-breaks-the-routing-in-asp-net-mvc) that it seems exactly like my scenario. But the solution suggested did not work for me.

This is what I've done at the moment:

**web.config**

```
<rewrite>
     <rules>
       <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url=".*" />
         <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
       </rule>
     </rules>
   </rewrite>
```

**_layout.cshtml**

```
<base href="/">
```

**app.js**

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
   $routeProvider
       .when('/', {
           templateUrl: '/MyAppView/Login'
       })
       .when('/Login', {
           templateUrl: '/MyAppView/Login'
       })
       .when('/Home', {
           templateUrl: '/MyAppView/Home'
       })
       [...]

       .otherwise('/Login')

   $locationProvider.html5Mode({
       enabled: true
   })
}
```

also tried to use this code in

**RouteConfig**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
       routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
       routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Default",
       url: "{*url}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
}
```

Every time, when I start debug on VS, my browser loads the template (e.g. the background image), but it crashes just before loading the login view. I've tried to use Chrome/IE11/Edge.

Comment: try to put in your webconfig  <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi thanks federico for your help. Now the browser doesn't crash but returns "failed to load template /MyAppView/Login" error

Comment: ok ..so check if the path is correct..and try maybe to do "./MyAppView/Login"

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi using "./MyAppView/Login" not crashes and it loads the template, but refreshing the page only the Login form is loaded (no background and AngularJS not working). Login is set as a Partial View in my application. If I try to use "./MyAppView/Index" (that is a View) it fails to load Login template.